# Dynamic SKU change with "Simple Configurable Products" Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, configurable, configurable-product

I have the free extension "Simple Configurable Products" installed but unfortunately, any updates/responses to it over on github are slow or nonexistant.

What I need the cart to do is to dynamically update the SKU when simple products are selected within the configurable product page.

I am able to get the cart to show the configurable product SKU, but it does not dynamically update when I select any of the simple products via the dropdown menu.

How can I get around this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out using the steps at this URL:
http://ashpointlane.com/2011/03/magento-dynamic-sku-display-on-configurable-products/

However it wasn't totally accurate, so I also made the changes afterwards suggested here after placing in that code: [Display Dynamic SKU on configurable product view Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444995/display-dynamic-sku-on-configurable-product-view-magento)

It's a little more tricky also if you have a custom theme, you'll have to do some more work getting the dynamic SKU to show on the frontend, and place where you want it to display.